# Inconveniente con la conversión de datos en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo agradezco por favor me colaboren con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta en cuanto a la conversión de tipo de dato en el lenguaje C#:

Tengo la siguientes líneas de código en este lenguaje:

```
Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Correo"], new CultureInfo("es-CO")),
Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cantidad"].ToString()),
Total = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Total"], new CultureInfo("es-CO"))
```

Y los errores que me aparecen son los siguientes:

Todos los errores son el CS0029, Pero para la siguiente línea de código:

```
Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Correo"], new CultureInfo("es-CO")),
```

me muestra lo siguiente:

No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'decimal' en 'string'

Para  lo  concerniente a la línea de código  ,

```
Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cantidad"].ToString()),
```

me  muestra lo siguiente:

No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'int' en 'string'

Para  lo  concerniente a la línea de código  ,

```
Total = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Total"], new CultureInfo("es-CO")),
```

me  muestra lo siguiente:

No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'decimal' en 'string'
Agradezco la colaboración que me puedan brindar para arreglar dichos inconvenientes.

Comment: Declara las variables con el tipo correcto `decimal Precio, Total;
int Cantidad;` o danos más contexto. ¿Qué es `dr`? ¿Cuáles son los tipos de `dr["Correo"]` y los otros valores de `dr`?

Comment: pero.. es claro.. haces un Convert. A algo, y luego las variables son todas texto.. te falta el toString en todos los casos...

Answer (score 1):

No nos has dicho de qué tipo son las variables `Precio`, `Cantidad`y `Total`, pero puedo deducir que son de tipo `string`.

`Convert.ToDecimal` devuelve un `decimal` y `Convert.ToInt32` devuelve un `int` y estás intentando asignar esos valores a variables de tipo `string`, `Precio`, `Cantidad` y `Total`. Eso no se puede hacer en C#, porque en C# sólo puedes asignar valores a variables cuando son del mismo tipo o son implícitamente convertibles, o sea que ni un `int` ni un `decimal` son `string` ni tampoco son implícitamente convertibles a `string`.

Supongo que dr es un `DataReader` obtenido de la base de datos, pero tampoco dices de qué tipo están declarados en la base de datos, así no nos lo pones muy fácil. Tampoco sabemos si admiten valores nulos, así que no sé si es necesario o no comprobarlo. Y que el precio lo obtengas del campo `Correo` no parece correcto.

`dr["Correo"]`, `dr["Cantidad"]` y `dr["Total"]` son de tipo `object`. Así que si quieres obtener su representación textual para una determinada cultura puedes usar `Convert.ToString`. Aquí tienes un fragmento de código que lo utiliza, pero no se hacen comprobaciones de valores nulos ni formatea los precios con un número concreto de decimales:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("es-CO");
Precio = Convert.ToString(dr["Correo"], culture);
Cantidad = Convert.ToString(dr["Cantidad"], culture);
Total = Convert.ToString(dr["Total"], culture);
```